# Disable a command button if mandatory fields are empty

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a form out of excel-ActiveX but I have no idea how I can make the command button disabled if all mandatory fields (textbox and combobox) are empty. I've attached the sample form for your reference.

[sample LA Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7vtX.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `*_Change` event for each control (and optionally the `UserForm_Activate` event) to set the `.Enabled` property for the Control Button.

For example, on a simple UserForm with 1 ComboBox (`ComboBox1`), 2 TextBoxes (`TextBox1` and `TextBox2`) and 1 CommandButton (`CommandButton1`), the following code will ensure that `CommandButton1` is disabled unless there is data in each of the other 3 controls:

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub CheckMandatoryFields()
    'Is a separate sub to make it easy to edit for all Controls at the same time
    If Len(TextBox1.Value) > 0 And Len(TextBox2.Value) > 0 And Len(ComboBox1.Value) > 0 Then
        CommandButton1.Enabled = True
    Else
        CommandButton1.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    MsgBox "Button is enabled!"
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    CheckMandatoryFields
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    CheckMandatoryFields
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_Change()
    CheckMandatoryFields
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    CheckMandatoryFields
End Sub
```

If your Buttons and Controls are in a Worksheet, then you need to change `UserForm_Activate` to `Worksheet_Activate`.  If they are in different worksheets, or some in a Worksheet and others in a UserForm, then you will need to Fully Qualify your references (e.g. `Sheet1.Textbox1.Value`)

If you are using Form Controls in a Worksheet instead of ActiveX controls, then you can't use the `_Change` events, and the way you Reference the objects is different:

```vb
Sheet1.Shapes("TextBox1").TextFrame2.TextRange.Text 'The value of TextBox1
Sheet1.Shapes("ComboBox1").ControlFormat.Value 'Which Number item in ComboBox1 is selected
Sheet1.Shapes("ComboBox1").ControlFormat.List(n) 'The value of the nth item in ComboBox1
```

A Form Control button does not have an `Enabled` property - however, if you have a "Do Nothing" macro, you can bodge it like so:

```vb
Sub DoNothing()
    'As it says
End Sub

Sub MakeASound()
    Beep
End Sub

Sub ToggleButton()
    If Sheet1.Shapes("Button 1").OnAction = "Sheet1!DoNothing" Then 'Disable Button 1
        Sheet1.Shapes("Button 1").OLEFormat.Object.Font.ColorIndex = 16 'Font colour = Grey
        Sheet1.Shapes("Button 1").OnAction = "Sheet1!DoNothing"
    Else 'Enable Button 1
        Sheet1.Shapes("Button 1").OLEFormat.Object.Font.ColorIndex = 1 'Font colour = Black
        Sheet1.Shapes("Button 1").OnAction = "Sheet1!MakeASound"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @curveball but this isn't working if the textbox and combo box are embedded in excel.

Comment: @AgapeCantuba Are you saying that the Textbox and Combo box are in a Worksheet instead of the UserForm?